# Links from the "Close" window opened in new tab, but links from the "Flag" window not

Tags: discussion, feature-request, user-interface

From "Close" window all links are opened in new tab:

> [image]

From "Flag" window links are opened in the same page:

> [image]

It makes me frustrated, especially if I click them by mistake from queue. Could you make links from "Flag" window be opened in new tab too?